# Incomplete entries in TOC in editor

Tags: table-of-contents, winedt

I am using winedt for MikTex. Problem is that I can't see  the section headings in the tree browser on the left window of Windedt. However, they do appear in PDF afterwards. Here is MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,Times]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{{\sffamily Main Title }}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section {\sffamily \textbf{Introduction1}}
\subsection {\sffamily \textbf{Introduction}}
This is the text for the introduction1.

\section {\sffamily \textbf{Introduction2}}
This is the text for the introduction2

\section {\sffamily \textbf{Introduction3}}
This is the text for the introduction3.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Side remark: You are doing something wrong if you add \sffamily\textbf to every \section. Change the style globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the space between the `\section` command and the opening curly brace `{`. Then it works as expected.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,Times]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{{\sffamily Main Title }}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{\sffamily \textbf{Introduction1}}
\subsection{\sffamily \textbf{Introduction}}
This is the text for the introduction1.

\section{\sffamily \textbf{Introduction2}}
This is the text for the introduction2

\section{\sffamily \textbf{Introduction3}}
This is the text for the introduction3.

\end{document}
```